# Number Calculation

Tags: c#, math

I am still new to C#, is there a way I can input total time on call and calculate those fees and cost?

Do I have to do a if statement that if minutes exceed 5 min it adds additional fee and how would I do that?

The cost of an international call is calculated as follows: 
Connection fee is $0.99; $0.15 the first 5 minutes; and $0.09 
for each additional minute

```
        double total, fee, firstmin, latermin;
        Console.Write("Call total time: ");
        total = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Looks like a homework. What have you tried already? Don't try to solve it completely in one statement. Just try to solve the problem one step at a time.

Comment: This is very easy to do with several different ways. This site however is not used as a service for getting code. What have you tried ? Then we may be able to help you.

Comment: Too many people treat programming as if it exists in a vacuum.  It doesn't.  Programming is just a way to implement solutions to real-world problems.  Solve the problem first and only then consider writing code.  Pick up a pen and paper and write down the steps that you would have to perform to solve this problem without code, like if it was all being done on paper.  Once you know the steps that you have to perform, then you can write code to implement those steps.  The reason that it's so hard to write code is because you don't even know what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Not homework just exercises prepare for if that question ever pops up again, not asking for answer asking for where should I start. Cant wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to calculate total cost as:

```
 if(total <= 5)
   fee=0.15;
 else 
    fee=0.15 + (0.09 * (total - 5));

 fee = connection_fee + fee;
```

Comment: Is there a way without if statement or is it the only solution?

Comment: You can also use ternary operator but that also works in same manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.Max` to avoid `if` statement.

```
fee = 0.99 + 0.15 + (0.09*(Math.Max(total - 5, 0)));
```

Comment: What does Math.Max do?

Comment: @TheBoringGuy It returns the maximum of the numbers in parameters, in this case maximum of `total-5` and `0`. This means if `total` is less than `5`, then it will return zero(not a negative value).